# Finding a specific user in Parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-studio-3.0

I have 2 users in the User class and they have ParseGeoPoint Column which I want to access. Those GeoPoints get updated with user's current latlng. I am allowing a user to manually add another person to see their location on the map. After the user give a username, this is what I've tried to get it's location:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
        parseQuery.whereEqualTo("username", username);
        parseQuery.setLimit(1);
        parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                if(e == null)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, objects.size() + " users found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

No matter what I do, I always get objects.size() as 0. I have tried hard-coding the username but still I get same results. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S This is my first time using Parse so be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("username", username);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // The query was successful.
    } else {
        // Something went wrong.
    }
  }
});
```

Try this code

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks a lot!!